# Add Hyperlink to all first column data using Bash script

Tags: python, linux, bash

I have log files which I am filtering to get some output like

```
WI_1_test  pass
WI_2_test fail
WI_3_test pass
```

I want to make all the data on the first column to have a hyperlink which is clickable...basically pointing to a url which is unique for each test.

with bash.

more explanation! I have a log file of test results and i want to prepare a report from the messy log. i am using awk to filter to the above WI_1_test pass ..etc. and below is my code.

```
awk '/rtest.rosunit-rtest/' logfilefromjenkins.txt \
| sed 's/^.*\(WI\).\([0-9]*\)..\([a-Z]*\).*/\1-\2,\3/g' \
|awk 'BEGIN{OFS="\t"}$1="http://testspec.net/#/project/workitem?id="$1'\
|sort  > testreport.csv    .
```

like so => my current result after i run the code above is outputting only the different links on the first column.

```
http://testspec.net/#/project/workitem?id=WI_1_test , pass

http://testspec.net/#/project/workitem?id=WI_2_test , fail
```

meanwhile my end goal is to have all the data as shown above on the first column pointing to unique urls, such that when i export a pdf report. just by clicking on any of the test on the first column the user can be redirected to the test url on the system.

This is my expectation for all column 1 data :

[WI_1_test](http://testspec.net/#/project/workitem?id=WI_1_test) , pass

[WI_2_test](http://testspec.net/#/project/workitem?id=WI_2_test) , fail

an idea on how to do this in python is also welcomed.

Answer (score 0):

You can't use text "clickable". The only way it's to print your hyperlien as plain text and to have a shell emulator who can make hyperlien "clickable".